# Keep remoting into wrong account. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a home theatre PC running with two users accounts on windows 7.
The default account logs into locally.  The account 'Paul' is present but is denied local log in so the default auto logs in locally.

I am trying to remote into account Paul using RDC however it tries to log into the default account and I am presented with an an option to boot the present user off so I can log in.

How do I specify which account I want to log into?

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to a Windows 7 machine with Remote Desktop, the local (console) user is disconnected.  Workstation versions of Windows do not allow multiple users to be logged in and working simultaneously.  Even if you log in with a second user acount, the console user must disconnect before you're allowed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you get a chance, you could install the free version of [Log Me In](http://www.logmein.com)

That way, you could use the LogMeIn account to get you out of the RDP conundrum w/o having to physically walk over to the remote computer.